# Is it possible to give Photoshop CS5 the Dark UI like CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5, photoshop-cs6

I have Adobe Photoshop CS5 (actually all the Adobe CS5 products), but the main feature of the newer CS6 products that I really like is the new Color of the UI. From photos and reviews I have seen and read, it seems that the CS6 family comes with four preset UI "themes" shown in the image below.

The one on the far right resembles what you are used to in the CS5 and older family. The image on the far left is the "Dark" UI option and what I really like about the CS6 family.

So I am asking others, is there a way to get the "Dark" UI (like the left image) in Adobe Photoshop CS5?

I'm using Windows 7 if that makes a difference.

[image: CS6 user interface]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, changing the colour of the interface isn't supported in Photoshop CS5. You may only change the colour of the area surrounding the document.